# PHP mkdir with special character creates wrong symbols directory

Tags: php, html, forms

I'd like to use special character because it's my procedure how to show galleries-folders on main page https://onlinegallery.online/admin/gallery/ . Folders are created by user input. Propably I don't want to use special characters for url's only for show content by glob.

```
$foldername= $_GET['tabl'] ; 
$meno= $_GET['meno'] ;                  
                $gallery = Db::queryAll('
        SELECT * FROM '.$foldername.'    
');


foreach ($gallery as $u)   
{         
        echo'<div class="section active" id=""><h1 class="headingfirst">'. htmlspecialchars($u["jmeno"]).'</h1>';
        $new = htmlspecialchars($u["jmeno"]);

    foreach (glob("$meno/$new/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
        $title = basename("$meno/$new/$filename", ".jpg").PHP_EOL;
    echo '<div class="slide"><img class="" src="https://onlinegallery.online/'.$filename.'" alt="'.$title.'"/><p class="imagetitle">'.$title.'</p></div>';  
}
```

I shouldn't use special characters as folder or file name.

Do I have to disallow special characters on user input ?

How could I solve this issue?

Users would like to name their galleries with diacritics.

Comment: Don't use characters with accents/diacritics in folder (and file) names. You can use some function that converts your characters to ASCII: https://php.vrana.cz/vytvoreni-pratelskeho-url.php (here is example function and I think you understand the whole article).

Comment: _“I would like to use characters like ľščťčž.”_ - no. No, you really wouldn’t. Not for anything that is likely to be used in an URL context later on. Plus, your file system might not necessarily use the encoding you expected it to in the first place. Especially on Windows, you might be dealing with some weird code pages, rather than actual UTF-8.

Comment: *"It works before"* - It worked before "what" exactly?

Comment: @rebosha In English please. Google translate says it means "Thank you" in your language, but Stack here is English. So please just say "Thank you".... *thank you*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encode it in utf8 in PHP?

utf8_encode($string)

[utf8_encode on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: I don't now how to use it. I tried something like that. `$folder = $_POST['folder']; $folder = mb_convert_encoding($folder, 'utf-8'); $dirPath = $folder;
$result = mkdir($dirPath);`

Comment: What is the php you use to make the directory (probably mkdir()). As seen in your snippet: you can do $result = mkdir(utf8_encode($dirPath));

Comment: I got this ÄÅ¥Å¾ÄÅ¥Å¾

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why should that help?